# Realm RealmMapView.toObject -- unsafeBitCast returns error -- swift 3.0.2

Tags: swift, realm

I've been trying the Building an iOS Clustered Map View for Swift, and every time I get the following error from the code below: fatal error: can't unsafeBitCast between types of different sizes

The error is being thrown in RealmMapView.toObject(), invoked as shown:

```
extension ViewController: MKMapViewDelegate {
  func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, didSelectAnnotationView view: MKAnnotationView) {
    if let safeObjects = ABFClusterAnnotationView.safeObjectsForClusterAnnotationView(view) {

      if let firstObjectName = safeObjects.first?.toObject(ABFRestaurantObject.self).name {
        print("First Object: \(firstObjectName)")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've never managed to get around this error. It seems like the framework is trying to convert an annotation to an ABFRestaurantObject, but maybe I'm confused. Is there a workaround for this, or am I just missing something?

Comment: This sounds like a bug with the RealmMapView library. It might be more appropriate to [file an issue reporting it on the RealmMapView GitHub repo](https://github.com/bigfish24/ABFRealmMapView/issues). :)

Comment: Thanks, I thought so too, but I know they hang out here too, so tried here first.